# Как сделать плавный переход на сайте

Tags: jquery, javascript

помогите или подскажите как правильно раелизовать такие переходы как в этом дизайне [link text](http://avathemes.com/HTML5/De7igner/image.php) нажмите на меню вверху сайта

Comment: @privetsh, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: я не школьник и не студент и это не задача, и я не прошу все делать за меня! я прошу подсказать натолкнуть и помочь разобраться потому что я в ява и квери полный ноль!!!

Comment: @privetsh здесь просто прокрутка в низ при нажатии на ссылку. А сначала, мне кажется можно загружать страницу загрузки, а затем аяксом контент сайта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак вот тут мой полностью работающий пример http://jsfiddle.net/pvkovalev/z84D9/

HTML

```
<a id="myAnchor3"><strong>Меню</strong></a>
<a href="#myAnchor1" rel="" class="anchorLink">Крути туда</a>
<a href="#myAnchor2" rel="" class="anchorLink">Крути сюда</a>
<p>Проснувшись однажды утром после беспокойного сна, Грегор Замза обнаружил, что он у себя в постели превратился в страшное насекомое. Лежа на панцирнотвердой спине, он видел, стоило ему приподнять голову, свой коричневый,...
    <p>
<a id="myAnchor1"><strong>Туда</strong></a>  <a href="#myAnchor3" class="anchorLink">Назад к меню</a>

        <p>Проснувшись однажды утром после беспокойного сна, Грегор Замза обнаружил, что он у себя в постели превратился в страшное насекомое. Лежа на панцирнотвердой спине, он видел, стоило ему ....
            <p>
<a id="myAnchor2"><strong>Сюда</strong></a><a href="#myAnchor3" class="anchorLink">Назад к меню</a>
```

JavaScript

```
$('a').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500);
    return false;
});
```

Надеюсь мой ответ будет вам полезен :-)

Comment: огромное спасибо!

Comment: @privetsh не за что :-)